Image in header tag is not showing in my EJS template
I'm creating a code which consists a form but the image in the header is not showing/popping up this is my current code as of now
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Serve static files from the 'assets' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));

let browserInstance; // Reuse browser instance

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('form');
});

app.post('/generate-pdf', async (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;

    try {
        const html = await ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'pdfTemplate.ejs'), data);

        if (!browserInstance) {
            browserInstance = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless: true, // Run in headless mode
                args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] // Required for Linux environments
            });
        }

        const page = await browserInstance.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html);
        
        // Set a longer timeout duration
        const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4', timeout: 9000000 });

        res.set({
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=application.pdf`,
        });
        res.send(pdf);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('PDF generation error:', error);
        res.status(500).send('PDF generation error');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});

Above is my app.js
below is the header code in my form.ejs
<header>
        <div class="header">
             <img src="/views/univ.png" alt="University Logo">
            <div class="header-text">
                <div class="main-title">University of the Philippines Baguio</div>
                <div class="sub-title">Graduate Program Office</div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </header>

I can't seem to find any solution for this
I expect to have the image shown in my page but It is not working.

GPO
--views
  --assets
    --univ.png
  --form.ejs
  --pdftemplate.ejs
app.js
htdocs.code-workspace
package-lock.json
package.json
render.sh


The problem is with .static method, where you provide assets folder, but it is actually nested in views folder, so it should be views/assets.
So, you need to either set correct paths, or rearrange folders.
Try providing full path to to static folder:
// views/assets
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'assets')));

and in the template, you just add image name, as the name of the static folder is not part of the URL:
<header>
    <div class="header">
         <img src="/univ.png" alt="University Logo">
        <div class="header-text">
            <div class="main-title">University of the Philippines Baguio</div>
            <div class="sub-title">Graduate Program Office</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

see: Serving static files in Express
